# qtHaveModule(ftp) not working in Qt 5

Tags: qt, qt5

I have two versions of Qt 5, one with compiled ftp module and anothed without. In *.pro file I've added

```
qtHaveModule(ftp):  #some code
!qtHaveModule(ftp): #some code
```

but for both versions of Qt qtHaveModule returns true. 
How can I check if ftp is present in Qt?

Comment: Maybe a syntax issue? How does the rest of the block look like? How do you know that qtHaveModule returns true?

Comment: @SimonWarta I've added simple message:
qtHaveModule(ftp):  message(ftp exists)
!qtHaveModule(ftp): message(ftp does not exists)
in Qt creator -> General messages is written: Project MESSAGE: ftp exists

Comment: thanks. I misread the question, first. Could you add the full setup how you did compile both Qt versions?

Comment: I've create a simple widgets project via Qt creator. Added qtHaveModule in *.pro file and rerun qmake.
Qt versions: 5.3, 5.4, 5.5.

Comment: How exactly did you "one with compiled ftp module and anothed without"? All paths, all commands please.

Comment: Downloaded sources [qftp](https://github.com/qtproject/qtftp) extracted them in qt folder. After that  did as described in readme.txt in qftp sources. Then opened /path/to/qtftp/src/src.pro (In my case C:\Qt\5.5\qtftp\src\src.pro) and compiled with nmake argument 'install'.

Comment: Qt without qftp downloaded from www.qt.io/download/

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#qthavemodule-name) says:

> **qtHaveModule(name)**
>
> Checks whether the Qt module specified by name is present. For a list of possible values, see [QT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qt).

Following the second list, you can see that ftp is not the name of any module.

Other than that, it is a [feature](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html#including-or-excluding-features) of the [network](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html) module.